# I don't think VS I don't suppose

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-choice

Could you please tell me whether the phrase "I don't suppose [something]" is idiomatic? If it is then what is the difference between:

> I don't think [something]
>
> I don't suppose [something]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I don't think" means that you are of the opinion that something isn't the case. " I don't think it is right to borrow money from people."

" I don't suppose" is used as a polite way of asking something, but it sounds formal and probably British: " I don't suppose you could lend me some money?" meaning could you lend me some money?

"

Comment: Thank you, but I've seen the phrase "I don't suppose" used to say something, not to ask. Can it be used NOT in questions?

Comment: Could you quote the phrase, please?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But It seems you are right that "I don't suppose" is used to introduce a polite question.

Comment: @Alexey *"No, I don't suppose I could."* As with the polite question, it can also be used as a polite (formal) statement, generally in response to the question. It can also be used outside of a reply without the negation. *"I suppose I should get out of bed now."* In that sense, it's neither formal nor polite, but has more of a conditional sense. It's a replacement for *maybe* or *I guess*.

Comment: Well, can we say "I don't suppose it is right to borrow money from people."? Is it idiomatic?

Comment: Like Jason said it is very formal.